# Combining universal coefficient theorems for alternate definition of cohomology with coefficients.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, derived-functors

I am studying cohomology using Chapter 3 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, and he defines (singular) cohomology with coefficients as follows:

Given a space $X$ and an abelian group $G$, we first take the singular chain complex with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, dualize by applying $\text{Hom}(-, G)$ to obtain the cochain complex, and then we let the $n$th cohomology group with $G$ coefficients $H^{n}(X; G)$ to be the $n$th homology group of this cochain complex.

But what if we instead want to take $G$ coefficients everywhere, and start out with the singular chain complex with $G$ coefficients? In other words, what if we instead took
$$  \cdots \xrightarrow[]{} C_{n+1}(X; G) \xrightarrow[]{\partial_{n+1}} C_{n}(X; G) \xrightarrow[]{\partial_{n}} C_{n-1}(X; G) \xrightarrow[]{} \cdots$$ to begin with (where $C_{n}(X; G)$ consists of formal sums of singular $n$-simplices with $G$ coefficents), dualized by applying $\text{Hom}(-, G)$ to obtain the cochain complex
$$\cdots \xleftarrow[]{} \text{Hom}(C_{n+1}(X; G), G) \xleftarrow[]{\delta_{n+1}} \text{Hom}(C_{n}(X; G), G) \xleftarrow[]{\delta_{n}} \text{Hom}(C_{n-1}(X; G), G) \xleftarrow[]{} \cdots,$$ and defined the alternate $n$th cohomology group with $G$ coefficients $h^{n}(X;G)$ to be the $n$th homology group of this cochain complex?

---

I know that if you put the universal coefficient theorem for homology and the universal coefficient theorem for cohomology, you can express $h^{n}(X;G)$ in terms of $\mathbb{Z}$-homology $H_{*}(X)$. To be more precise, from the universal coefficient theorems we have the following split short exact sequences for a chain complex $C$ of free abelian groups:
$$0 \to H_{n}(C) \otimes G \to H_{n}(C; G) \to \text{Tor}(H_{n-1}(C), G) \to 0$$ and

$$0 \to \text{Ext}(H_{n-1}(C), G) \to H^{n}(C; G) \to \text{Hom}(H_{n}(C), G) \to 0.$$

Taking $C$ to be
$$  \cdots \xrightarrow[]{} C_{n+1}(X; G) \xrightarrow[]{\partial_{n+1}} C_{n}(X; G) \xrightarrow[]{\partial_{n}} C_{n-1}(X; G) \xrightarrow[]{} \cdots,$$ it follows from the second split short exact sequence that
$$h^{n}(X; G) = H^{n}(C; G) \cong \text{Ext}(H_{n-1}(C), G) \oplus \text{Hom}(H_{n}(C), G) = \text{Ext}(H_{n-1}(X; G), G) \oplus \text{Hom}(H_{n}(X; G), G).$$

Then, taking $C$ to be the singular chain complex for $X$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, it follows from the first split short exact sequence that
$$H_{n}(X; G) \cong (H_{n}(X) \otimes G) \oplus \text{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X), G).$$

Putting these two together, we have
\begin{align*}
h^{n}(X; G) &\cong \text{Ext}\left((H_{n-1}(X) \otimes G) \oplus \text{Tor}(H_{n-2}(X), G), G\right) \\ & \hphantom{1} \hphantom{1} \hphantom{1} \oplus \text{Hom}((H_{n}(X) \otimes G) \oplus \text{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X), G), G)\\
&\cong \text{Ext}(H_{n-1}(X) \otimes G, G) \oplus \text{Ext}(\text{Tor}(H_{n-2}(X), G), G) \\ & \hphantom{1} \hphantom{1} \hphantom{1} \oplus \text{Hom}(H_{n}(X) \otimes G, G) \oplus \text{Hom}(\text{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X), G), G).
\end{align*}

---

My question is: **is there any way to simplify the ugly expression for** $h^{n}(X; G)$ **above to better see what is going on?**

One observation:

- I know that by the [tensor-hom adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction) we can write
  $$\text{Hom}(H_{n}(X) \otimes G, G) \cong \text{Hom}(H_{n}(X), \text{Hom}(G, G)).$$ So, $h^{n}(X; G)$ contains information about what happens when we dualize $H_{n}(X)$ with respect to $\text{Hom}(G, G)$, which is sort of what we expect (because we dualized with respect to $G$ twice).

I don't really know what to do with $\text{Ext}$ and $\text{Tor}$ when the group $G$ is not $\mathbb{Z}$, so I'm a bit stuck on the other terms. I tried making the assumption that $H_{*}(X)$ was finitely generated, but it didn't help much.

Comment: You can apply the tensor-hom adjunction at the chain level to see that your $h^n(X;G)$ is actually $H^n(X,\mathrm{Hom}(G,G))$. I think that will be the most convenient description. If you apply UCT to this and expand everything out, it will probably lead to the same monstrosity as in your question. I'm not sure what you actually want, though. This is certainly the simplest description, but the final sentence sounds like you'd rather know whether/how this can be computed practically.

Comment: @Thorgott That actually helps a lot! Just to clarify: each chain group $C_{n}(X; G)$ is the same as $C_{n}(X) \otimes G$. So, instead of tensoring first with $G$ and then applying $\text{Hom}(-, G)$, we can just apply $\text{Hom}(-, \text{Hom}(G, G))$ from the start.

Comment: @Thorgott It would be nice to know how this can be computed practically (I have no idea what happens when you have nested $\text{Ext}$ and $\text{Tor}$), but I suppose it's at least as hard as computing $\text{Hom}(G, G)$.

Comment: If $G$ is finitely generated abelian, this is completely algorithmic. If $G$ is not finitely generated abelian, the question becomes a lot deeper and I don't really know outside of simple examples where you can wing it.